# Variant delegates in variant interfaces. Confused

Tags: c#, .net

Earlier I had a good understanding of variance in interfaces. Now I'm a little confused with the variance in delegates in variant interfaces. Methods, properties, indexers, and events can be defined in interfaces. The signature of methods, properties and indexers in the variant interface is direct. And the events are reversed.

I don’t understand why a value-returning method works in a covariant interface, but a similar signature for a delegate does not work. A contravariant delegate that should not return anything works. The same goes for the contravariant interface.

Code below:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    delegate T MyDelegateReturn<out T>();
    delegate void MyDelegateTake<in T>(T t);

    interface IMyInterfaceReturn<out T>
    {
        T MyMethodReturn(); //signature with return value and interface with keyword out - ok

        //event MyDelegateReturn<T> MyEventReturn; //delegate signature with return value but is error CS1961

        event MyDelegateTake<T> MyEventTake; //delegate signature with take parameter but why it is work?
    }

    interface IMyInterfaceTake<in T>
    {
        void MyMethodTake(T t); //signature with take argument and interface with keyword in - ok

        //event MyDelegateTake<T> MyEventTake; //delegate signature with take parameter but is  error CS1961

        event MyDelegateReturn<T> MyEventReturn; //delegate signature with return value but why it is work?
    }

    class MyClass<T> : IMyInterfaceReturn<T>, IMyInterfaceTake<T>
    {
        public event MyDelegateTake<T> MyEventTake;
        public event MyDelegateReturn<T> MyEventReturn;

        public T MyMethodReturn()
        {
            return default;
        }

        public void MyMethodTake(T t)
        {

        }
    }

    class A
    {

    }

    class B : A
    {

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            B MyMethodReturn()
            {
                return default;
            }

            void MyMethodTake(A i)
            {

            }

            MyClass<B> myClass1 = new MyClass<B>();
            myClass1.MyEventTake += MyMethodTake;

            MyClass<A> myClass2 = new MyClass<A>();
            myClass2.MyEventReturn += MyMethodReturn;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question lacks a **question**. Please fix your post so that it includes a [mcve], along with a detailed explanation of what that code does, how that's different from what you want (or expect), and what _specifically_ you need help with. Please make sure that there's some sentiment expressed as an actual _question_ that someone can respond to.

Comment: @PeterDuniho They've included the questions in the comments of the code.

Comment: @Sweeper: I don't find the comments very clear in terms of a _question_ (specifically, given that the language specification and documentation explains exactly why the code works or doesn't work the way it does or doesn't, what precisely is there to not understand?), but even if they were, that's not where a question belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule is that the types of events must be *input-safe*. This is the same as method parameters. This makes sense, because when you declare events in interface decelerations, you're essentially declaring a pair of `add` and `remove` accessors, that look something like this:

```
void add_MyEventTake(MyDelegateTake<T> value);
void remove_MyEventTake(MyDelegateTake<T> value);
```

These will be called when you use `+=` and `-=` on the event.

So to simplify things, we'll consider methods that accept `MyDelegateTake` and `MyDelegateReturn`.

```
interface IMyInterfaceReturn<out T>
{
    T Get();
    void add_MyEventTake(MyDelegateTake<T> t);

}
```

There is a [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/interfaces#variance-safety) in the C# spec that describes the rules. You can check out the rules if you want, but I'll try to explain this more intuitively.

At the end of the section, it describes how to interpret "input-safe" and "output-safe" intuitively:

> Intuitively, an output-unsafe type is prohibited in an output position, and an input-unsafe type is prohibited in an input position.
>
> A type is output-safe if it is not output-unsafe, and input-safe if it is not input-unsafe.

In `IMyInterfaceReturn`, `T` is covariant, so output-safe, and so should only be used in an "output position". I will now show that the parameter `MyDelegateTake<T>` is indeed an "output position".

Suppose you have an implementation of `IMyInterfaceReturn<string>` called `Foo`:

```
class Foo : IMyInterfaceReturn<string>
{
    public void add_MyEventTake(MyDelegateTake<string> t)
    {
        t(Get());
    }

    public string Get()
    {
        return "Something produced by Foo";
    }
}
```

you can use `Foo` like this:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.add_MyEventTake(str => /* do something with str */);
```

Wouldn't you agree that `str` is some sort of "output" of `Foo`? The above code is really just the following, but in a more indirect way:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var str = foo.Get();
// do something with str...
```

Therefore, it follows that `T` is in an output position, and you can safely do things like assign `foo` to a variable of type `IMyInterfaceReturn<object>`.

If `add_MyEventTake` took a `MyDelegateReturn` however, `add_MyEventTake` would be a *consumer* of `T`, and `T` would be in an input position. `Foo` could be used like this:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.add_MyEventTake(() => "Some Input For Foo!");
// this is just a roundabout way of doing:
foo.add_MyEventTake("Some Input Fo Foo!");
```

And suppose that `Foo` were implemented like this:

```
class Foo : IMyInterfaceReturn<string>
{
    private string s;

    public void add_MyEventTake(MyDelegateReturn<string> t)
    {
        s = t();
    }

    public string Get()
    {
        return s.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Then this code would break:

```
IMyInterfaceReturn<object> foo = new Foo();
foo.add_MyEventTake(() => new object());
foo.Get(); // what would this do? object has no ToUpper!?
```