# Variant delegates in variant interfaces. Confused

Tags: c#, .net

Earlier I had a good understanding of variance in interfaces. Now I'm a little confused with the variance in delegates in variant interfaces. Methods, properties, indexers, and events can be defined in interfaces. The signature of methods, properties and indexers in the variant interface is direct. And the events are reversed.

I don’t understand why a value-returning method works in a covariant interface, but a similar signature for a delegate does not work. A contravariant delegate that should not return anything works. The same goes for the contravariant interface.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    delegate T MyDelegateReturn<out T>();
    delegate void MyDelegateTake<in T>(T t);

    interface IMyInterfaceReturn<out T>
    {
        T MyMethodReturn(); //signature with return value and interface with keyword out - ok

        //event MyDelegateReturn<T> MyEventReturn; //delegate signature with return value but is error CS1961

        event MyDelegateTake<T> MyEventTake; //delegate signature with take parameter but why it is work?
    }

    interface IMyInterfaceTake<in T>
    {
        void MyMethodTake(T t); //signature with take argument and interface with keyword in - ok

        //event MyDelegateTake<T> MyEventTake; //delegate signature with take parameter but is  error CS1961

        event MyDelegateReturn<T> MyEventReturn; //delegate signature with return value but why it is work?
    }

    class MyClass<T> : IMyInterfaceReturn<T>, IMyInterfaceTake<T>
    {
        public event MyDelegateTake<T> MyEventTake;
        public event MyDelegateReturn<T> MyEventReturn;

        public T MyMethodReturn()
        {
            return default;
        }

        public void MyMethodTake(T t)
        {

        }
    }

    class A
    {

    }

    class B : A
    {

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            B MyMethodReturn()
            {
                return default;
            }

            void MyMethodTake(A i)
            {

            }

            MyClass<B> myClass1 = new MyClass<B>();
            myClass1.MyEventTake += MyMethodTake;

            MyClass<A> myClass2 = new MyClass<A>();
            myClass2.MyEventReturn += MyMethodReturn;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An event is *called* from the code implementing the interface. So your interface dictates that the type can pass values *outwards*, and you have an event (that will be called by that type) that takes a parameter (and the event handler is on the outside), hence it moves out from the type.

Comment: Why did you repost [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67768761/variant-delegates-in-variant-interfaces-confused)? Did my answer help? Keep in mind that you should edit your question, rather than posting a new one, if you want to clarify things.

Comment: @Sweeper: That's a really great, well-formulated answer. OP should at least rephrase this new question in such way that it becomes clear why that your old answer doesn't answer the question. Otherwise, I propose posting your answer here again.

Comment: @Sweeper I propose undeleting that one and deleting this one

Comment: @Charlieface I agree. Casted my undelete vote and edited.